# Create a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ORDER':["A", "A", "A", "B", "B","B"], 'GROUP': ["A1C", "A1", "B1", "B1C", "M1", "M1C"]})
df['_A1_XYZ'] = 1
df['_A1C_XYZ'] = 2
df['_B1_XYZ'] = 3
df['_B1C_XYZ'] = 4
df['_M1_XYZ'] = 5
df

    ORDER   GROUP   _A1_XYZ   _A1C_XYZ   _B1_XYZ      _B1C_XYZ  _M1_XYZ
0   A       A1C      1          2             3       4          5     
1   A       A1       1          2             3       4          5     
2   A       B1       1          2             3       4          5     
3   B       B1C      1          2             3       4          5     
4   B       M1       1          2             3       4          5     
5   B       M1C      1          2             3       4          5
```

I want to create a column "NEW" based on column "GROUP" and all the columns that ends with *XYZ as below:
Based on the value of GROUP for each row df["NEW"] = df["*_XYZ"].

For example, for 1st row, GROUP = A1C, So "NEW" = 2 (_A1C_XYZ), Similarly for 2nd row "NEW" = 1 (_A1_XYZ)

My expected output

```
    ORDER   GROUP   _A1_XYZ   _A1C_XYZ   _B1_XYZ      _B1C_XYZ  _M1_XYZ      NEW
0   A       A1C      1          2             3       4          5           2
1   A       A1       1          2             3       4          5           1
2   A       B1       1          2             3       4          5           3
3   B       B1C      1          2             3       4          5           4
4   B       M1       1          2             3       4          5           5
5   B       M1C      1          2             3       4          5
```

Comment: IS the B1C_XYZ column correct, or should it be _B1C_XYZ?

Comment: @DavidErickson It should be _B1C_XYZ. Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.lookup`:

```
df['NEW'] = df.lookup(df.index, '_'+df['GROUP']+'_XYZ')
df
```

Output:

```
  ORDER GROUP  _A1_XYZ  _A1C_XYZ  _B1_XYZ  _B1C_XYZ  _M1_XYZ  _M1C_XYZ  NEW
0     A   A1C        1         2        3         4        5         6    2
1     A    A1        1         2        3         4        5         6    1
2     A    B1        1         2        3         4        5         6    3
3     B   B1C        1         2        3         4        5         6    4
4     B    M1        1         2        3         4        5         6    5
5     B   M1C        1         2        3         4        5         6    6
```

---

#### Updated after question edited.

Or use stack and reindex,

```
(df['New'] = df.stack().reindex(zip(df.index, '_'+dfl['GROUP']+'_XYZ'))
               .rename('NEW').reset_index(level=1, drop=True))

df
```

Output:

```
  ORDER GROUP  _A1_XYZ  _A1C_XYZ  _B1_XYZ  _B1C_XYZ  _M1_XYZ  New
0     A   A1C        1         2        3         4        5    2
1     A    A1        1         2        3         4        5    1
2     A    B1        1         2        3         4        5    3
3     B   B1C        1         2        3         4        5    4
4     B    M1        1         2        3         4        5    5
5     B   M1C        1         2        3         4        5  NaN
```

Comment: This solution will not work if any of the values in GROUP doesnot have the corresponding column name. For example, for last row, the group value is M1C but we dont have "_M1C_XYZ", it should return nan

Answer (score 0):

@ScottBoston's answer is better if all of the values in the rows are also columns, but I thought I'd share mine! Essentially, I create a new dataframe with the relevant columns, drop the duplicates, change the column names, transpose the dataframe and merge the column back in...

```
a = df.iloc[:,2:].drop_duplicates()
a.columns = [col.split('_')[1] for col in df.columns if '_' in col]
a = a.T.rename({0:'NEW'}, axis=1)
df = pd.merge(df, a, how='left', left_on='GROUP', right_index=True)
df
```

output:

```
ORDER   GROUP   _A1_XYZ _A1C_XYZ    _B1_XYZ _B1C_XYZ    _M1_XYZ  NEW
0   A   A1C     1       2           3       4           5        2.0
1   A   A1      1       2           3       4           5        1.0
2   A   B1      1       2           3       4           5        3.0
3   B   B1C     1       2           3       4           5        4.0
4   B   M1      1       2           3       4           5        5.0
5   B   M1C     1       2           3       4           5        NaN
```